# PowerApps - adding same set of data in multiple time

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

I am trying to doing powerapps

I created a design something similar to this

[image: design]

I want to  the same design in 10 times.. 10 set of design.. How can I do this..
Now what I am doing is, I created 1st set and copy paste to 10 times and again and again adjusting the position. Is this a correct method?  how can we reuse the same design ? I tried component, but data source binding is not possible in component..
how can I do this?

[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the components, group them, and you only have to readjust your group.